# Does auto_load to 'no' in wp_options improve performance

Tags: database, performance, options

I am trying to improve the performance of a wordpress based blog. I am looking at wp_options table and am thinking to set the column auto_load  to 'no'.

Does it have any side-effect on the site itself ? Does it improve the performance of the site ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on content and context.

Options with `autoload = yes` are loaded very early, all in one query. This is pretty fast, but it might be *too* early when an options contains a serialized object whose class isn’t loaded yet.

Options with `autoload = no` are loaded when `get_option()` is called.

Use `yes` when …

- ( you need the option on (almost) every page load *or*
- you don’t know when you will need the option *or*
- the option value is very small )
  *and*
- the value is not a serialized object

Use `no` in all other cases, or refactor the code to make it “yes-compatible”.

You have to weight the number of database requests against the size of the transferred content. When in doubt, measure both.